# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. in c#

Tags: c#, plot, charts, serial-port, port

I want to plot datas that I read from serial port after see them in richtextBox. But I got that error. Please help. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change UI components from any thread other than the main thread.

Try the following:

```
richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text = val.ToString(); }));
```

Invoke causes the given action to be run on the UI Thread.

Comment: @rhsn then you have to do the same with the chart (you have to invoke it). Otherwise, consider providing code for the chart as well.

Comment: @rhsn If you got the same error then it should be fairly obvious what is required to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception tells you, you tried to access the UI element on another thread than it was created on. You must know however that UI elements can only be accessed by the thread on which you created them. You probably created this UI element on the main thread (Which means in that case that you created it normally, not in asynchronous context) but tried to access it in another thread (probably in asynchronous context). To access it anyway you must invoke whatever you want to do with the element on the thread you created it. However you don't have to know on which thread you created it, as the UI element knows it itself. To invoke it on it's thread use `Invoke`:

```
var val1 = (string)val.Clone();
if(richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text = val1));
else
    richTextBox1.Text = val1;
```

You can see that I copied the value to another variable, which can be useful as the variable `val` could be changed while assigning the value to the text of the RTB. Furthermore I checked wether an invoke is actually required, because it doesn't have to get invoked if it's already on the correct thread.

Comment: I got error a lot area. Actually I didn't understand error.

Comment: @rhsn then provide the code in which you get the errors - otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I wrote that part to plot graph:  ' this.chart1.Series["Datas"].Points.AddXY(z, s);'  But I got that error:  Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'chart1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Then you got to do the same as I did in my code example except that you replace the part `richTextBox1.Text = val1` with `this.chart1.Series["Datas"].Points.AddXY(z, s);`, don't you?

Comment: Could you then edit your post with the new code you tried?

Comment: Yes, but program again and again gave same error and now with new codes c# didn't read datas form serial port

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141523/discussion-between-metacolon-and-rhsn).